# Importing same icon from different style with icon library (FontAwesome5 for Angular)

Tags: angular-fontawesome

Readme file on [GitHub](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#using-the-icon-library) shows how to import icons from different pack. For example:

```
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faArrowAltRight } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';
library.add(faCoffee, faArrowAltRight);
```

but there is no example how to import same icon from different styles. I did it like this:

```
import { faHome as falHome } from "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons";
import { faHome } from "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons";
library.add(falHome, faHome);
```

but this is not pretty, since I need to specific `as` for all icons that are duplicated, but from different styles.

So, I came up with an idea with importing entire lib, but adding just some icons:

```
import * as fal from "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons";
import * as far from "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons";
library.add(fal.faHome, far.faHome);
```

I am not sure if I can expect bigger final size or any other performance problems in this case.
Adding entire library is not recommended ([from GitHub readme](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#using-the-icon-library)):

> You can also import entire icon styles. But be careful! Whatever you
>   import may end up bloating your final bundle with icons you're not
>   using.
>
> `library.add(fal, far);`

but I am not adding entire library, just importing.

I did some test and compare file size (`main.js`) and build time. They are approximately the same (`2280.098 kB` vs `2280,988 kB` and `5:19` vs `5:15`).

But I am not an expert on TypeScript or Angular and I would like to know if this should work (same size and production build time) or it just accidentally the same and this could change in any future?
My basic instincts tells me it shouldn't be the same, since I am importing entire library. But I already read something about tree-shaking and importing entire library shouldn't be the problem, since tree-shaking ignores all unused icons (imports). Is this true?